# How to change Android ViewPager Background Color?

Tags: android, background, android-viewpager

`ViewPager` Background is grey. I can't find on internet any clear article that shows how to just change that background color in black for example.Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve it in 2 ways,

1.Add the following in your `ViewPager` in the xml

```
android:background="#000000"
```

2.Do it dynamically like below,

```
ViewPager pager= (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
private ViewPager mPager;
mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 3):

A `ViewPager` is not grey by default, it's transparent like other `ViewGroup`s, so you will see your parent layout background or window background by default.

If you want to change the background color of your whole Activity, I suggest that you override the `android:windowBackground` attribute in your Activity's theme, which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to `ViewPager` in your xml file

and set `android:background="@android:color/black"` for parent layout.

I hope this will help.